# Vuforia dynamically add model target

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am working on my Master's degree thesis and :

I have a trouble finding out if newest vuforia is somehow allowing user to dynamically (for example in script) add new Model targets to recognize.

I am using Unity with vuforia library.

As far as i understand it i have to create a database and train it with my models, If i want to add or delete a target I need to delete and create a new database.

So is there a way to create an application with vuforia that will be able to run on its own and i will be able to change the database in app and it will take that dabase's models?

Or it's static and i have to do it manually and rebuild the app?

I was searching a web, but i could not find a conclusion if its possible or not, any help would be appreciated. And if anyone got any other suggestion as to how can i achieve someting like these i would really appreciate that.

I found on documentation there is possibility to add target images, but nothing on model target, as i need to change the database and add a bunch of exported files to resources and assets.

Comment: May be this guide can help https://developer.vuforia.com/library/unity-extension/create-and-load-targets-unity

Comment: This is the exact page i was reffering to in my post and this is only about Image Target

Comment: With small modifications the same logic should apply to databases containing any type of target.